# Nginx with wordpress serving blank pages

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress

Title; I get served a blank page with a 200 status code in my logs and no body after the webpage successfully loads. Here is my config file:

```
root var/www/sitename;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name sitename.com www.sitename.com;

location/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php) (/.+?)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastbgi_index index.php;
}
```

There are other entries but I can't copy them and they are irrelevant anyway.

I've tried various methods and spent hours and have gotten some progress, but now I'm stuck here.
One more thing is that I'm trying to run WordPress and this is the only site block that is giving me problems. The default installation block works fine with a custom html page.

EDIT: I solved the problem by changing the php location block to

```
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
```

instead of what I had before.

Comment: Check your PHP errors.

Comment: Forgot to say I have no errors, but I fixed it anyway